# Swiperjs Detect Swipe Direction?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm creating a calendar web app that shows each day's memos I took.
[image: studia app]

It looks like this, and I wanted to add a "swipe" gesture for mobile users.

And then, I realized `swiperjs`. I created a swiper with only 1 slide and gave it a `loop`. It worked perfectly.

But the problem is that the swiper index always gives me 1.

Using event listeners (like `slideChange`) I need to detect the swipe direction and load the next day's memos.

Is there a specific event listener (something like `swipeLeft`) or a value returned that gives me the direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found it.

```
on: {
  slideChange: (swiper) => {
    console.log(swiper.touches.diff < 0);
  }
}
```

Returns true when swipe right, false when left.

**NOTE:**
`swiper.touches.diff` will be 0 when the slide is changed by the Navigation Arrows. To do that add event listeners to the buttons, too.

Answer (score 3):

From the swiperjs documentattion, there are events to detect swipe direction like 'slideNextTransitionEnd' and 'slidePrevTransitionEnd'.
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-slideNextTransitionEnd

Example:

```
on: {
      slideNextTransitionEnd: (swiper) => {
        console.log('SWIPED RIGHT')
      },
      slidePrevTransitionEnd: (swiper) => {
        console.log('SWIPED LEFT')
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this works well

```
const direction = swiper.touches.startX > swiper.touches.currentX ? 'forward' : 'backward';
```